# Convert simple C #define's into Rust constants

Tags: c, rust, c-preprocessor

I have a proprietary library with a long story and 30KLoC header. I'd like to generate bindings for Rust to it. And I've used `bindgen` crate almost successfully. Except `bindgen` can't transform macro constants into normal constants. Because those constants are defined in a fuzzy way, like

```
#define CONSTANT ((const_type)SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT)
```

So, is there some way to translate such half-constants into normal Rust ones:

```
const Type name = value;
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently, crate `bindgen` uses `clang` as its backend. And `clang` is able to deal with macro definitions and other such stuff, if right flag is provided to parser. So, can anyone advice good tutorial on dealing with macro definitions using `libclang` API?

Comment: Asking for tools/books/etc... is off-topic on Stack-Overflow unfortunately. A simple trick would be to reword the question to just ask "how to" instead of specifying that you are looking for a tool... after all there may be a tool-less way of doing it.

Comment: In C, the general answer is "no". This is because literals are considered *constant expressions*, whereas variables with a `const` qualifier are not. And there are some contexts in C where a *constant expression* is required (for example, initializers for static variables).  So this change might break the program.

Answer (score 0):

Running the headers through `gcc -E` (i.e. the preprocessor) will remove the `#define`s. It may remove more than you want though.

If you want to selectively preprocess, there used to be a utility called `scpp` that did that. I can't immediately find a reference to it other than to some tar files to download, but you may have more luck.

Comment: That's what I  struggle against. There are several hundreds of constants defined via `#define`. And I need to preserve them.

Comment: @Target-san with `-dM` or `-dD` you can preserve macros (the difference is "only" vs "both")